# Get list of installed applications on connected iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa

I have a mac application that needs to get the list of installed applications on the connected iPhone. How can it be done? Or can it be done at all? Private api is also fine

Comment: You should ask Bhargarv Rao for what he considers a better response than one that tells you the exact method to call on the private framework that is otherwise undocumented every where else.  End snark.

Comment: Just because you can list the apps, that doesn't mean you will be able to transfer their documents back.  Only apps that are configured to share their document folders via iTunes are readable.

Comment: The secret is the UIFileSharingEnabled key in the applications Info.plist - if that isn't set, then there is no way for a Mac app to retrieve content from the AFC daemon.  iTunes uses the "backup" daemon instead, and the last time I tried that needed some secret sauce - i.e., normal apps couldn't do it.